# non of IF/ElSE works on SDK Build version

Tags: android, if-statement, toast

I use this simple condition check to show a Toast but none of them is shown:

```
 public void ShowVersion(){

         //This works So I am sure the method is called:
         //Toast.makeText(this,"Method is called",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Version Supported",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Version not supported",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

How it is possible that none of **if** and **else** work?

Comment: `How it is possible that none of if and else work?` Meaning that Toast is not showing up?

Comment: Yes I mean that. The toast works when it is out of if/else so I think none of those conditions are true @Blackbelt

Comment: it is not possible for both branches of an if/else to not be executed. If you step through it with a debugger you will see that one of them is executed. Probably there is another issue, show more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was an exception inside the IF block. The exceptions breaks `IF / ELSE` block. A `try/catch` block can help detect problem in similar cases.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public void ShowVersion(){

     //This works So I am sure the method is called:
     //Toast.makeText(this,"Method is called",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=11) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Version Supported",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Version not supported",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

OR a more elegant way would be:

```
public void ShowVersion(){

     //This works So I am sure the method is called:
     //Toast.makeText(this,"Method is called",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Version Supported",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Version not supported",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Same output! I can even Toast `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` and get 26 when the toas is outside of if/else block.

Comment: Did the 2nd way also give the same result?

Comment: this is literally doing the same

Comment: yeah I know but when one fails you do everything else at the top of your head. Your code looks correct so try restarting Android studio and invalidating Caches. I'll check more on my lap when I reach home.

Comment: It works on my lap. I seriously have no clue what's wrong.